# Send Notification to Gear 2

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

So in the http://img-developer.samsung.com/contents/cmm/SamsungGearApplication_UID...

I've found the notifications panel. I have a host android app on my phone. Can someone point me to a guide/tutorial on how to get the notification produced by my Android App onto the Watch? My setup is Master-Slave Linked App. And Once User pressed the notification on the watch, it will pull up the corresponding Gear 2 App?

2.2. Notifications 
Unlike the phone’s notification panel, Notifications app substitutes for its function in Gear. Gear’s 
notifications are placed on the home screen to the right of the clock and users can change its position. Its 
notifications are synced with the connected device’s notification panel. The numbers of unread notifications 
are displayed on the badge. If a user reads notifications on either device, the read notifications on both 
devices will disappear or be marked as read. Users can choose which notification to show on Gear in ‘Gear 
Manager’.

When users’ mobile device is not connected to the Gear via Bluetooth, notifications of incoming 
calls/messages will not be sent to the Gear. After reconnecting, any missed notifications that users have not 
read on their mobile device will be sent to the Gear. ‘Limit notifications’ option in Gear Manager stops 
notifications being sent to the Gear when users are using their mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can't access the Notification API from watch, it is private. You can just enable push notifications from gear 2, and send regular push notification to your phone. It will then be picked up by the gear 2. This is the best you can do.

Comment: Yes, you can, but you have to implement the part to receive and send notification, I answered it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305213/notification-in-gear2-app/25083889#25083889